# Using Sql parameters on Ingres Database error

Tags: c#, spring.net, sqlparameter, ingres

Exception:

**Local variable/parameter ':your-param-name' can only be used within a database procedure.**

In MSSQL, the param character is @. In INGRES Database, really is ***:*** ? I cannot find official documentation for that...

> SELECT * FROM MyIngresTable WHERE MyColumn = :poorParam

C# with Spring.NET AdoTemplate:

```
IDbParametersBuilder builder = CreateDbParametersBuilder();

builder.Create().Name("poorParam").Type(DbType.Int32).Value(1);
```

Any help?

Comment: Instead of using Spring.NET, try to execute an ADO.NET Command directly. *Can* you create a parameter? Does the driver support parameterized queries? What driver are you using? I remember that IBM hadn't released ADO.NET 2.0 drivers for *years* after .NET 2.0 was released. The driver or database may simply not support parameterized queries. One got the impression that they really wanted people to move to DB2

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Just use **INTERROGATION** without named param, and **pass values in order of usage**.

```
        string query = "SELECT * FROM MyIngresTable WHERE MyColumn >= ? and OtherColumn = ?";

        IDbParametersBuilder builder = CreateDbParametersBuilder();

        builder.Create().Type(DbType.Int32).Value(10);
        builder.Create().Type(DbType.String).Size(4).Value("test");

        IList<YourModelType> data = AdoTemplate.QueryWithRowMapper(
            CommandType.Text,
            query,
            new YourRowMapper<YourModelType>(),
            builder.GetParameters()
        );
```

Another tip about Spring.NET AdoTemplate:

```
    using Spring.Data.Common;
    using Spring.Data.Generic;

    protected virtual IDbParametersBuilder CreateDbParametersBuilder()
    {
        return new DbParametersBuilder(AdoTemplate.DbProvider);
    }
```

Thanks also, Panagiotis Kanavos.